# Escaping content in @section tag

Tags: laravel, xss, laravel-blade, sanitization

I've defined a Blade section called `title`, which I use like, for example, `@section('title', 'Log in')`, which will then get printed as `<h1>Log in</h1>`. However on some pages the title will be determined by user input (namely `$subject`). I've found that if I do `@section('title', $subject->name)` then this value will not be escaped which leaves my site open to XSS attacks. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel you can use the `e` helper function to escape values. You should be able to do something like this:

```
@section('title', e($subject->name))
```

If you take a look in the `BladeCompiler` code, you can see that Laravel itself converts the default escaped output (`{{ }}`) into `e(..)`